# Windows Touchpad: TIP TAP right click -> Two finger tap when one finger is down

Tags: windows, synaptics-touchpad

I have *Synaptics* Trackpad on which I can *two-finger-tap* to emulate a right-click. However it is not so convenient when one of my fingers is already touching the trackpad that I need to lift that finger and press it simultaneously with another finger in sync with the former.

I need to be able to trigger the *two-finger-tap* functionality **by tapping my midfinger when my forefinger is touching** (or by tapping my ring finger when my midfinger is touching), and how do I do it?

Registry hacks are welcome.

---

PS: I have seen this functionality in a few *ELAN* touchpads but this wasn't called something (that I can possible use to search the web) or there was no option to enable or disable this specific feature in two-finger  taps.

EDIT: I finally found all the swipe features and their corresponding names at MultiSwipe (http://www.multiswipe.com) and unfortunately it's not opensourced! So, I'm asking about TIP TAPs - specifically about **assigning tip tap right to right click**

Comment: Which version of touchpad (+ laptop model) do you have? Which OS? Have you already updated to latest driver?

Comment: AFAIK, this feature is not present in any version of _Synaptics_ on all versions of _windows_; It's not a bug, but I need it to work like _ELAN_. Btw, I'm using `Synaptics v19.0.12.95` and my laptop model is `HP G6 1068se`

Comment: found the name of that feature finally: TIP TAP...!